# How do I convert these Haxe source files to Python?

Tags: python, game-physics, haxe, nape

I am trying to port the Nape physics engine (written in Haxe) to a language not supported by Haxe (Xojo). Now I don't understand Haxe but I am comfortable in Python. I'm trying to convert the mass of .hx files to python source files so I can then translate them to Xojo.

I have the Nape .hx source files (from haxelib) and have installed the haxe command line tool.

I have tried multiple permutations to try to convert the .hx files to Python files but am having no success. I have tried the following:

`haxe -cp <directory containing some .hx files> -python <output directory>`

That just outputs help from the haxe tool.

`haxe <directory containing .hx files> -python <output directory>`

That throws:

> Error: Could not process argument
>   [directory] Class name must start with
>   uppercase character

I've tried just processing one .hx file:

`haxe <.hx file> -python <output directory>`

> Error: Could not process argument
>   [myfile.hx] empty part

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I thought the whole point of Haxe was to be able to easily convert to different languages?

Comment: You need to also specify `-main dot_path` where `dot_path` is the main class (ie the starting point of the program).

Comment: ... which will be difficult, as Nape appears to be a library rather than a program, and as such doesn't *have* a main class. Maybe one of the test suites? You probably want something which exercises most or all of the code paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hugh is right in that you normally need to specify a `-main` argument. However, you can omit that and compile a single module as well if you don't need to have an entry point (for example when compiling a library like in your case):

> `<dot-path>` : compile the module specified by dot-path

It think doesn't really matter much which module you choose here. I went with `nape.Config`. The important part is using `--macro include` to make sure every file in the nape lib is compiled (otherwise only the ones referenced are included).

```
haxe nape.Config -lib nape -python nape.py --macro include('nape') --macro include('zpp_nape')
```

This command produces a `nape.py` file with around 121000 lines, which might be a bit prohibitive depending on how much work is needed to convert Python code to this Xojo language. Even if that's a simple process, generated code is typically not the most readable.

In fact, Nape's Haxe version is already not very readable, since it is generated by a preprocessor called [caxe](https://github.com/deltaluca/caxe) (`.cx`). The caxe source of Nape can be found [here](https://github.com/deltaluca/nape/tree/master/cx-src).

---

There's some compiler options you could try here to reduce the code size a bit and make it more readable:

- `--no-inline`: prevents code form being inlined, reducing the output to ~60000 lines
- `-D NAPE_RELEASE_BUILD`: Nape define that removes error handling - probably not worth it, only removes ~2000 more lines.