# What should my Python program include in order to use compiled Haxe object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, haxe

I know, It's a very trivial question, but I haven't found any example, so I am stucked now.

I have a very simple Haxe object. This is the content of the file `Thing.hx`:

```
@Persistent
class Thing {
  @Property
  public var thingName: String;
}
```

I can compile it:

```
haxe Thing.hx -python Thing.py
```

The result is some magic, the content of `Thing.py` is:

```
class Thing:

  pass

  Thing.__meta__ = _hx_AnonObject({'obj': _hx_AnonObject({'Persistent': None}), 'fields': _hx_AnonObject({'thingName': _hx_AnonObject({'Property': None})})})
```

My `DoTheThing.py` Python program wants to use this:

```
import Thing
```

But it fails right on the `import` statement:

```
NameError: name '_hx_AnonObject' is not defined
```

Also, in my real project, I have a more complex Haxe class, which, when I include it from Python, occurs this error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'python_Boot' has no attribute 'keywords'
```

What Python modules should they include? How can I figure out, what modules should I include for my Haxe classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I've figured out that I need to add some `haxe` compiler option to include the missing methods.

First I needed to install `nape`:

```
haxelib install nape
```

Then compile:

```
haxe -lib nape Thing.hx -python Thing.py --macro "include('nape')" --macro "include('zpp_nape')"
```

*(Source: [How do I convert these Haxe source files to Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35419868/how-do-i-convert-these-haxe-source-files-to-python))*